# как в JQuery дописать чтот к елементу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

у меня есть

```
<div class="content"><spam class="sometext">Тут какойто </spam></div>
```

как мне с помощю jquery не переписать а дописать текст ?

```
$(".sometext").text("Текст");
```

Comment: `spam` - новый тег ,специально для спамеров?) Попробуйте `$(".sometext").text($(".sometext").text() +"Текст")`

Comment: текст можно заменить, заменить вы можете на новый, как тут, либо взять старый и прибавить новый, а потом результат вставить.

Comment: спасибо я поставил spam просто так \

Comment: для примера и всьо

Comment: `$(".sometext").append('Текст');`